# Can I run Windows online games on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, games

I'm a newbie in using Ubuntu. I have wubi right now.

I know the basics, but I don't know if I can install Windows online games (such as League of Legends) on Ubuntu and use them without problems.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This should be possible with WINE. however, running Ubuntu using Wubi causes a performance hit, so programs don't run quite as well, this is usually a minor issue, but could get worse when trying to run games.  WINE can cause a slight performance hit as well, again usually not noticeable, but add the two together and you may find that performance is poor.

Comment: dual boot is always a better choice if you want to game with your computer and in windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can play League of Legends with wine

Check how well the game works with wine here:

https://www.winehq.org/

The easiest way to use wine is to install [playonlinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/)

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E0F72778C4676186
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```